# How to add exsiting feilds from a form to an existing table in Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to add three fields which are automatically calculated from a form to an existing Table with three more columns in Microsoft Access?

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of forms in the world of MS Access: unbound forms and bound forms.  Here is an example of an unbound form.

Unbound Forms

```
Let us look into Unbound Forms −

    These forms are not connected to an underlying record or data source.
    Unbound forms could be dialog boxes, switch boards, or navigation forms.
    In other words, unbound forms are typically used to navigate or interact with the database at large, as opposed to the data itself.
```

Bound Forms

```
Let us now understand what Bound Forms are −

    Bound forms are connected to some underlying data source such as a table, query, or SQL statement.
    Bound forms are what people typically think of when they think of the purpose of a form.
    Forms are to be filled out or used to enter or edit data in a database.
    Examples of bound forms will typically be what users use to enter, view or edit data in a database.
```

Now, let's look at an example of a unbound form.

```
Basically it is a form that is not bound to any database table or query. You can usually determine if a form (or a control on a form) is bound by looking at its record source property which will either be bound to a Table, Query or SQL String. Also if you look at each control on the form you will find that each control has a Control Source, which is derived from the field names made available in the Record Source. A bound form is easier to create and requires minimal programming (if any). It allows for rapid application development since Microsoft Access is designed to make application development fast and easy. An unbound form on the other hand requires a lot of programming, BUT gives you near total control over how your application is going to work. This in some cases outweighs the numerous benefits offered by bound forms.



The Database

The contacts database has one table called contact with the following fields:
Field Name  Data Type
cid (Primary Key)   AutoNumber
name    Text
address     Text
email   Text
occupation  Text
age     Text

Copy and paste or import the following sample data into the contact table:

1,"Axaro Dausab","255 Amite Street","ax@dausab.com","Market analyst","20"
2,"Khagu Noabes","58 Xamiseb Road","khagu@noabes.com","Medical Student","22"
3,"Dantago Nuseb","2 Nuseb Street","dan@nuseb.com","Medical Student","22"
4,"Phuna Noabeb","2 Nuseb Street","phuna@noabeb.com","Web Designer","30"
5,"Aribasen Seibeb","58 Xamiseb Road","areez@seibeb.com","Researcher","35"
6,"Zion Maletzky","58 Xamiseb Road","zion@maletzky.com","Web Designer","20"
7,"Leidago Noabeb","277 Mudi Road","leidago@noabeb.com","Web Designer","30"
8,"Amite Itheke","26 Shanke Road","am@itheke.com","Market Analyst","40"
9,"Amire Ganuseb","23 Ganuseb Road","amire@ganuseb.com","Fashion Designer","45"
10,"Dinashange Develo","40 Develo Road","dina@shange.com","Journalist","23"

If you want to use your own data it is fine, but for the sake of facilitating things I would recommend using the sample data.

So the structure of your contact table should now resemble something like this:
```

[image]

```
The Contact table in design view

And with sample data it should look something like this:
```

[image]

You can download a working example from the link below.

http://www.databasedev.co.uk/unbound-forms.html

Now, let's look at an example of a bound form.

```
To create a form with a single click,1.Open the table or query upon which you want to base the form.2.To create a form on which all fields from the underlying table or query are placed, displaying one record at a time, on the Createtab, click Form.
```

[image]

See this for more details.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ms_access/ms_access_create_form.htm